# setState in useEffect depanding on props.location.state, doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, use-effect, use-state

I do not understand what I am missing here, I would be very grateful for your help!

I'm getting to my "Test" functional component, from another functional component, by the command history.push (urlState).

"urlState" is an object, which I check its values in the useEffect function of the "Test" component.

Based on the values in urlState, I decide whether to execute "setRequestNumber" and "setRequestSubNumber", and which values to send to them.

But the set functions do not work !!

What am I doing wrong ??

(I want useEffect to run only once, so I left the dependencies array-blank.)

Here is my code-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {URL} from "../../config/Constants"

const Test = (props) => {
  const [requestNumber, setRequestNumber] = useState(0);
  const [requestSubNumber, setRequestSubNumber] = useState(1);

  const getRequestDetails = async (fetchURL) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(fetchURL);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("something went wrong!");
      }
      const body = await response.json();
      const result = body.results;
      console.log(result); //result will be rendered instead of <h1>Hi there!</h1>
    } catch (error) {}
  };

  const getNextRequestCounter = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${URL}/requests/requestCounter`);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("something went wrong!");
      }
      const body = await response.json();
      const result = body.results[0];
      setRequestNumber(result);
    } catch (error) {
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    var urlState = {
      request: 1,
      subRequest: 2,
      isNewRequest: false,
      originalSubRequest: 1,
    }; // That what I have in props.location.state;
    
    var fetchURL = "";
    if (urlState.isNewRequest) {
      getNextRequestCounter();
      fetchURL = `${URL}/requests/${requestNumber}/${requestSubNumber}`;
    } else {
      setRequestNumber(urlState.request);
      setRequestSubNumber(urlState.subRequest);
      fetchURL = `${URL}/requests/${requestNumber}/${urlState.originalSubRequest}`;
    }
    getRequestDetails(fetchURL);
  }, []);
  return <h1>Hi there!</h1>;
};
export default Test;
```

Thank you!

Comment: You are always returning (rendering) `<h1>Hi there!</h1>`, no matter what, you have no conditional rendering.

Comment: This is not what I meant, and this is not my problem.

<h1> Hi there! </h1>, this is just mock data. My problem is that requestNumber remains 0 and requestSubNumber remains 1 and is not updated according to the conditional statement in useEffect